# How to Zip collection of files and folders

Tags: zip

**How to zip files and folders which are in a particular directory using Node JS** ? I have abc directory under which there are some .xml, .rels etc. files, and a few folder workbook, styles, etc. Now I want to zip files under abc folder with the name abc.zip

I don't want the zip to happen with the abc directory i.e. abc.zip -> abc -> and those files; **I want abc.zip-> those files**.

Currently using JSZIP which is creating the files on generate. but i want to create the files and folders first and then ZIP them

Expected->
on unzipping the abc.zip file -> 
workbook (Folder)
styles (Folder)
content.xml (File)

should be extracted instead of "abc" folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zip-lib).

```
var zl = require("zip-lib");

zl.archiveFolder("path/to/abc", "path/to/abc.zip").then(function () {
    console.log("done");
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

`path/to/abc.zip` archive file directory will be as follows:

```
path/to/abc.zip
.
├── file.xml
├── workbook
├── styles
└── file2.rels
```